# Comparing values of two arrays

Tags: c, arrays, coordinates

I have two arrays containing, each one, values of the coordinates. In other words, the first array contains the values of the x and the second array contains the values of the y. The goal consists of not having equal coordinates, which means that every coordinate must be different from all the others. I tried to do this:

```
for (i=0; i<len(lrs)-1; i++) {
    for (j=0; j<len(lrs) ; j++) {
        if ((pos.x[j]==pos.x[i+1])&&(pos.y[j]==pos.y[i+1]))
           printf("1");
    }
}
```

However, there's a moment where the values of the "j" and "i" are the same and, therefore, the condition is verified, which is not intended. Maybe I'm not thinking the right way, but I just can't figure it out.

Comment: Only check the condition if `i != j` and done.

Comment: check if(i != j) condition

Comment: If the number of elements is large this is very inefficient.

Comment: If your values are float or double (and according to source of data), comparing them this way may be inacurate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is better to make inner loop for j > i only:

```
for (i=0; i<len(lrs); i++) {
    for (j=i+1; j<len(lrs) ; j++) {
        if ((pos.x[j]==pos.x[i])&&(pos.y[j]==pos.y[i]))
           printf("1");
    }
}
```

In this case you will never check condition i==j. More over you will check each pair only once.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I wanted!